# How to call to a delayed distributed function in python

Tags: python

I have an async python code running on several servers in parallel.
I need to schedule a delayed call to a function f1().
For example - I need function f1 to be called in 60 seconds from now.

As my application is stateless, I don't care if the function is called on the same server that scheduled it, or any other.
Moreover, the server that scheduled the delayed call might be scaled down between scheduling and calling.

Question - is there any python package that can support the delayed distributed function calls as described above?

Answer (score -1):

try to use:

```
import time
time.sleep(60)
```

befor the line that you want it to be delayed

Comment: This will completely halt the program for a minute (not good), not to mention it doesn't align with the distributed system requirement that @diemacht stated.